# async_wait() in boost::asio fires immediately when io_service.run() is after try-catch

Tags: c++, boost, try-catch, boost-asio

I've modified boost::asio's [Timer.4](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer4/src.html) example and call the printer class with a second parameter interval and throw if interval is less than one.

The timer is fired after the specified time when io.run() is inside the try-catch.

```
boost::asio::io_service io;

try {
    Printer p { io, 2 };
    p.print();
    io.run();
} catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

But when I move it below the try-catch is fires immediately.

```
try {
    Printer p { io, 2 };
    p.print();
} catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}

io.run();
```

There is probably a logical explanation it fires immediately outside the try-catch. Can someone shed light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `p` is destroying when you leave try-catch scope. C++ has  RAII programming technique. Read more about this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii

The following example should work:

```
Printer p { io, 2 };
try {
    p.print();
} catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
}

io.run();
```